# a hotkey for entering text-editing mode with Type tool in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Is there any hotkey assigned for entering into text-editing mode with Type tool in illustrator? Without using too much mouse clicking, this would be definitely helpful for my design work productivity.
I wonder if there is any for this?

Any advice would be very much appreciate?

Comment: You mean something other than hitting `T` to load the cursor?

Comment: Press the "T" key to select Type Tool

Comment: Usually, in Fireworks at least, you hover over a tool to show its title with the hotkey in brackets (if assigned)

Answer (score 5):

T for the type tool or simply double-click text to enter editing mode.

Comment: ...and then when you're in a text frame, `Escape` takes you out of it and puts you back into selection mode (`V`), and automatically selects the text frame you were in. Same in InDesign, Photoshop etc.

Answer (score 0):

When already in editing mode of one text, you could just mark/select other text elements with the mouse. This makes it easier to edit multiple texts in a row.

The problem lies in how I have to switch between keyboard writing and mouse modifier workflow quickly for just a simple thing as editing a little text.

There's additional annoyance when I try to continue using the mouse before I start writing, but the doubleclick hits the resize handles. With trackpad if I move the mouse a bit, it fails to recognise the doubleclick as a doublclick etc.

Comment: `t` key then click. Not sure where the problem is.

Comment: Scott:
It grinds my gears.
I'll add a technical explanation in my answer.

Comment: You do realize Illustrator has never been designed to be a text-based application. Just like Photoshop is better for raster imaged, InDesign is better for large amounts of text.

Comment: No, it's not that. 
Indesign are for multipagd documents.
Illustrator is good for large texts, the problem I have comes with multiple small text-tags.

Comment: uhm.. `t`.... click, edit, `Esc`...  click, edit, `Esc`...  click, edit, `Esc`

Comment: Hmm, yeah...

I still have the feeling that it could be done in a better way.

Change workflow..., change workflow..., change workflow..., change workflow..., change workflow...

And for every time, I have to refocus my eyes when I look down on the keyboard. I don't think it's a problem at work in the early hours, but my creativity blossoms when my brain is nearly drained on energy, and I'm in some kind of trance-like state of mind to let the thoughts flow freely.

Comment: I think maybe that different workflows requires different electrical tensions in your brain, and different neurotransmitters runs better with different tensions. This process drains your brain very fast.

Do you really need to be double clicking a text to edit it, when it's already selected and you press "t"? It's just pisses me off when I try to dblclk and I instead resize the text. It happens frequently. Maybee I could try to zoom in and out to avoid it, but still...